# Remap modifier key events about to be delivered to an application

Tags: keyboard, xorg

One cross-platform application on my Ubuntu machine uses modifier keys to perform certain functions. However, wherever Alt is used to perform these functions on Windows and Mac, the developers decided that the Meta key is required instead on Linux.

I don't know why this decision was made - I hope there was a legitimate reason for it - but it's *incredibly* annoying because the Meta key is used for the window manager shortcuts on Ubuntu, so the key events never reach the application in question. For example, where a lasso select requires holding Alt while dragging the mouse on Windows and Mac, holding Meta while dragging the mouse on Ubuntu just moves the application window itself on screen.

I absolutely **do not** want to have to change all the window manager shortcuts just so I can use this one program, and to my knowledge I am not able to change the Meta key requirement in the application itself. What I would like to be able to do is hijack the key event just before it's delivered to the application - that way, I can press Alt and have the application receive the message with the Meta keycode instead.

To avoid confusion, I **don't** want to do the following:

- Make the Alt key behave like the Meta key at a keyboard/system level. This would just leave me with the same problem, as the window manager and the application would both now respond to the Alt key instead.
- Change the window manager dependency on the Meta key. I like the Meta-based shortcuts and want to continue using them in all instances.

The ideal solution I'm thinking of would be something like:

- I press (or relase) the Alt key.
- The key event is handled as normal, however X11 likes to do its thing. If any existing shortcuts use Alt and take precedence over the application window, they would work as normal.
- It is determined that the key message should be directed to the application that is currently in focus.
- **If** this application is the one I specify, and the key code of the key message is that of Alt, the code is changed to Meta.
- The message is dispatched to the application.

Essentially, I just want to be able to use my Alt key where I'm used to using it in this application! There should be no other observable effects: the Alt key should function as normal in all other instances/applications.

I have tried using AutoKey - however, it assumes that your hotkey combinations will not be based solely on a modifier key, so it won't let me bind anything to just Alt. I know for a fact that `xev` picks up the Alt key event.

Is there any way I can accomplish this type of key mapping?

Answer (score 0):

It is quite hard to modify events to a single window. One alternative is to run a separate X11 server, with just your application running within it. You can then use xmodmap or similar to change keyboard mappings for that server, i.e. just for that application.  Xnest runs a separate server within a window. Try playing with something like

```
Xnest :1 -noreset &
DISPLAY=:1 xmodmap -e 'keysym a = b B b B'
DISPLAY=:1 xev -event keyboard
```

Put the mouse in the xev window and type "a" and it will appear as a KeyPress event with keysym b.